# T-SQL SELECT query to return combined result of multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am wondering if it is possible and more efficient to do something that I am presently doing in code, to do in T-SQL instead.

I have a database with courses. Each course can have different offerings which are variations of the course at different locations and at different awards.

Here's my (simplified) database structure and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tblCourse (CourseId int, CourseName varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE tblOffering (OfferingId int, CourseId int, LocationId int, AwardId int)
CREATE TABLE tblLocation (LocationId int, LocationName varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE tblAward (AwardId int, AwardName varchar(50))

INSERT INTO tblCourse VALUES (1, 'Course A')
INSERT INTO tblCourse VALUES (2, 'Course B')

INSERT INTO tblOffering VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO tblOffering VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO tblOffering VALUES (3, 1, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO tblOffering VALUES (4, 1, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO tblOffering VALUES (5, 2, 3, 1)

INSERT INTO tblLocation VALUES (1, 'Location A')
INSERT INTO tblLocation VALUES (2, 'Location B')
INSERT INTO tblLocation VALUES (3, 'Location C')

INSERT INTO tblAward VALUES (1, 'Award A')
INSERT INTO tblAward VALUES (2, 'Award B')
```

What I want to retrieve from SQL is a single row for each course/award combination. Each row would have columns for each location and whether a course of that CourseId/AwardId combination was available. There would be now rows for course/award combinations that have no offerings.

The required result, from the sample data, would be a recordset like this:

```
CourseId | CourseName | AwardId | AwardName | LocationA | LocationB | LocationC
---------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
1        | Course A   | 1       | Award A   | True      | True      | True
1        | Course A   | 2       | Award B   | True      | NULL      | NULL
2        | Course B   | 1       | Award A   | NULL      | NULL      | True
```

(NULL could also be False)

At present I am doing a simple SELECT statement with various JOINS which gives me multiple rows for each course/award combination, then I loop through all rows in my code and build the required result. However, I don't think this is so efficient as I also need to page results.

I think I could do this fairly easily in a stored procedure by creating a temporary table and a bunch of separate queries, but I don't think that would be too efficient. Wondering if there is a better way of doing it in T-SQL???

So to clarify, what I am looking for is a T-SQL query or stored procedure that will produce the above sample recordset, and which I could adapt paging to.

NB. I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: This wouldn't be homework since it doesn't have the `homework` tag, right?  Could you edit your question to include your query with the `INNER` and `OUTER` (wink, wink) `JOIN`s?  Paging is often done within a query.  I'm sure there are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: It is certainly not homework. The current select query is written in Linq to SQL and the table structure bears little resemblence to the simplified table structure in my sample above but if it proves anything I will add it to my question shortly. I mentioned paging because currently I do the paging in my code (C#) and I have to build the entire recordset before I can extract just the page requested, that's why I thought it would be better to do this at the database level instead so I don't have to move all data from database to application just for one page.

Comment: Can you post your current query?

Comment: Begging your pardon, but I didn't recognize you from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185281/recursive-query-to-check-that-all-parents-are-enabled).  [This search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination+sql-server) should give you some options for adding pagination.  Working on some SQL and noticed that both your `tblAward` ids are 1.

Comment: Thank you for your help with the previous question. I just fixed the duplicate tblAward IDs in my sample - that was a copy+paste error. I am not concerned with how to do paging as I do know how to do this in T-SQL already, just how to produce the required recordset if it is possible.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the answer I was hoping for. I would like to remove my current code from the question if everybody agrees as I think it detracts from the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Dynamic columns:

```
DECLARE  @COLUMNS VARCHAR(max)
        ,@query varchar(1024)
        ,@True varchar(6)


SELECT @COLUMNS = 
COALESCE(
@Columns + ',[' + L.LocationName + ']',
'[' + L.LocationName +']'
)
FROM tblLocation L

SELECT @True = '''True'''

SELECT @QUERY = 'SELECT C.CourseName
                 ,A.AwardName
                 , pvt.*
FROM (SELECT O.OfferingID AS OID
            ,O.AwardID AS AID
            ,O.CourseID AS CID
            ,L.LocationName AS LID
       FROM tblOffering O Inner Join tblLocation L on L.LocationID = O.LocationID) AS S
PIVOT
(
    count(oID) For LID IN (' +@COLUMNS+ ')
) As pvt
inner join tblCourse C on C.CourseID = CID
inner join tblAward A on A.AwardID = pvt.AID'

EXEC (@QUERY)
GO
```

Comment: There was a bad join with my original post.  I have since corrected, and reposted.  Also included screen shot of proof of results.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work well, but what happens if more locations are added? Is it possible to not have the locations hard-coded in the query?

Comment: It is possible.  However, now variables come into play.  :(
Oh, also, i'm not sure why, but there appears to be '\' in front of the brackets in my query, but in the Screen Cap, they are not there.  Not sure if this is an auto-formatting thing on the site.  Please omit them, i'll try to correct the Code.

Comment: If I add some extra data - INSERT INTO tblOffering VALUES (5, 2, 4, 1); INSERT INTO tblLocation VALUES (4, 'Location D') - it doesn't add the extra column for LocationId 4. Does the CASE WHEN pvt.[x] need to made dyanmic too?

Comment: Yes, if left out of the select statement, it will not display the column, so as the query is written, each new location will need a case statement.  Can you live with having the columns in a different order and possibly lose the Location column names: 'Location A'...etc?

Comment: I can see that I can change the LocationId to LocationName by changing the inner SELECT query and adding a JOIN, as I need the Name more than the Id. And if I add an order by clause to where @COLUMNS is generated it seems I can reorder the location columns. I think this looks to be the best solution and I am reading up now and learning about PIVOT tables so thanks for your answer.

Comment: I made the changes in the code to reflect using LocationName instead of LocationID.  This solution now returns a 1 or a 0 instead of True and False, which can be cast as boolean types in C#, correct?

Answer (score 3):

This will produce a paginated version of your example results:

```
declare @tblCourse as table (CourseId int, CourseName varchar(50)) 
declare @tblOffering as table (OfferingId int, CourseId int, LocationId int, AwardId int) 
declare @tblLocation as table (LocationId int, LocationName varchar(50))
declare @tblAward as table (AwardId int, AwardName varchar(50)) 

INSERT INTO @tblCourse VALUES (1, 'Course A') 
INSERT INTO @tblCourse VALUES (2, 'Course B') 

INSERT INTO @tblOffering VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1) 
INSERT INTO @tblOffering VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1) 
INSERT INTO @tblOffering VALUES (3, 1, 3, 1) 
INSERT INTO @tblOffering VALUES (4, 1, 1, 2) 
INSERT INTO @tblOffering VALUES (5, 2, 3, 1) 

INSERT INTO @tblLocation VALUES (1, 'Location A') 
INSERT INTO @tblLocation VALUES (2, 'Location B') 
INSERT INTO @tblLocation VALUES (3, 'Location C') 

INSERT INTO @tblAward VALUES (1, 'Award A') 
INSERT INTO @tblAward VALUES (2, 'Award B') -- This had id 1 in your example.

-- Set the following parameters to control paging:
declare @PageSize as Int = 5
declare @PageNumber as Int = 1

; with CourseAwardSummary as (
  select distinct C.CourseId, C.CourseName, A.AwardId, A.AwardName,
    case when exists ( select 42 from @tblOffering where CourseId = C.CourseId and AwardId = A.AwardId and LocationId = 1 ) then 'True' end as LocationA,
    case when exists ( select 42 from @tblOffering where CourseId = C.CourseId and AwardId = A.AwardId and LocationId = 2 ) then 'True' end as LocationB,
    case when exists ( select 42 from @tblOffering where CourseId = C.CourseId and AwardId = A.AwardId and LocationId = 3 ) then 'True' end as LocationC
  from @tblCourse as C inner join
    @tblOffering as O on O.CourseId = C.CourseId inner join
    @tblAward as A on A.AwardId = O.AwardId
    ),
  CourseAwardSummaryRows as (
    select *, Row_Number() over ( order by CourseName, AwardName ) as RowNumber
      from CourseAwardSummary
    )
    select CourseId, CourseName, AwardId, AwardName, LocationA, LocationB, LocationC
  from CourseAwardSummaryRows
  where ( @PageNumber - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1 <= RowNumber and RowNumber <= @PageNumber * @PageSize
  order by CourseName, AwardName
```

Comment: Works perfectly and paging is a bonus. What happens if the list of locations increases? Is it possible to make the query work without having to change it if the locations change?

Comment: It's not going to generate columns on the fly as `tblLocation` changes.  Looks like TexasTubb wins this round.  (And I have to beat Gordon Linoff's aggregation technique into my tiny brain.  He keeps pulling it out of his pocket and I keep forgetting it.)

Answer (score 1):

The following query does this by joining and aggregating the offering table, and then joining the result to the course and award tables:

```
select c.CourseId, c.CourseName, oa.AwardId, oa.AwardName,
       oa.LocationA, oa.LocationB, oa.LocationC
from tblCourse c left outer join
     (select o.CourseId, o.AwardId, a.awardName
             max(case when LocationName = 'Location A' then 'true' end) as LocationA,
             max(case when LocationName = 'Location B' then 'true' end) as LocationB,
             max(case when LocationName = 'Location C' then 'true' end) as LocationC
      from tblOffering o join
           tblLocation l
           on o.LocationId = l.LocationId join
           tblAward a
           on a.awardID = o.AwardId
      group by o.CourseId, o.AwardId, a.awardName
     ) oa
     on oa.CourseId = c.CourseId
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, as tblAward does not contain a column called CourseId.